# SharePoint Designer 2010 get DAY from current date or due date

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

In SharePoint desinger workflow from Due Date or Created Date I want to take DAY but unable to get the day.
Data Source = Current Task
Field from Source = Due Date
Return Field as = Long Date

Result I am getting - 20 July 2019. Not getting the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround, Create a calculated column to get the day of date field.

```
=TEXT([Created],"DD")
```

Then, you could use the calculated column in workflow.